# How can I check each character in a character array?

Tags: java, string, boolean

How can I check each character in a character array against a string? For example, I want to check these characters: `!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),_,+` against the string `af!a$co`. Without regex, though.

Does this make sense?

```
public boolean IllSymbols(String newString)
{
   char [] data = {'!', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')' };
   String str = new String(data);
   for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
   {
      for (int j=0; j<local.length(); j++)
      {
        if (str.charAt(i)==local.charAt(j))
        {
             return true;
         }

       }

   }
   return false;
}
```

But when I check the word `af!a$co` in my main method

```
if (IllSymbols(newString)==true)
{
  return false; // false = text is illegal
}
else
{
  return true; // true = text is legal
}
```

The devil returns the string as 'true', meaning that it's a legal string. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Your last piece of code is pretty clumsy. It can be simplified as `return !IllSymbols(newString);`. Complex boolean logic, huh? :)

Comment: Your code doesn't look at the string that is passed in.  It is comparing str to local, not to newString.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public boolean hasIllegalCharacters(String newString) {
  boolean hasIllegalChars = false;
  char[] illegalChars = {'!', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')' };

  for (int i = 0; i < newString.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < illegalChars.length; j++) {
      if (newString.charAt(i) == illgalChars[j]) {
        hasIllegalChars = true;
      }
    }
  }

  return hasIllegalChars;
}
```

The idea here is that you start by assuming it's going to be false, and only set it to true if you find an illegal character.

If you want to return as soon as the first illegal char is found, then right after the line `hasIllegalChars = true;` you can add a `break;` statement.

To look at the opposite case, if you want to return true **only if** `newString` contains **nothing but** illegal characters, then you could flip things around, start by assuming it's true and initializing `hasIllegalChars` to `true`, and then setting it to `false` inside the nested `for` loops if anything that is **not** an illegal character is found, with this code (the `for` loops and method declaration is the same):

```
  hasIllegalCharacters = true;

  ...nested for loops...
    if (newString.charAt(i) != illegalChars[j]) {
      hasIllegalChars = false;
      // optional "break;" or "return false;" statement here
    }
  ...

  return hasIllegalChars;
```

...but in that case I would recommend renaming the method to "isAllIllegalCharacters" or something similar.

Comment: Or if you want to return as soon as you find an illegal character, instead of a break put in a return.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean illSymbols(String newString) {
    char [] data = {'!', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')' };
    for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        if(newString.indexOf(data[i]) > -1) { // if the string contains the character
            return false;                     // return false
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to check if some `String` contains any of the characters `!`, `@`, `#`, `$`, `%`, `^`, `&`, `*`, `(`, `)`, `_`, `+`, in which case it's illegal? For pure ease of use and understanding, I'd suggest [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)'s [CharMatcher](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) class.

```
private static final CharMatcher ILLEGAL_SYMBOLS = 
    CharMatcher.anyOf("!@#$%^&*()_+");

public boolean isLegal(String string) {
  return ILLEGAL_SYMBOLS.matchesNoneOf(string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use .contains()

```
....

for(int i=0; i < check.length; i++){

    for(int j=0; j < illegalChar.length; i++){
        if(check[i].contains(illegalChar[j])
        return false;
    }

}

return true;

....
```